# Does Android cache the libraries?

Tags: android, device-driver

I am working on a device driver which android apps use. Whenever I make a small modification to the driver and recompile the modified drivers, it seems like the app is not using the modified driver but still use=ing the previous version. I am sure about this because the modifications made includes print statement which doesn't showup when the app runs.

However, once I delete the driver and rebuild it or restart the system then it seems to work fine.
The problem with doing this is that it is time consuming, because I have to be sure that the app is using the latest driver.

So my question is that whether android cache the libraries? If so are there any simple hacks to prevent it from doing so?

**EDIT**:
  As a matter of fact I can delete my device driver and the app which uses it still runs without reporting a problem about missing driver !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How do you install the driver? Is it part of the app? (reinstalling apps should not cache anything)

Comment: U build the driver( right now I am cross compiling) and then save it in /system/lib .... so that the app will pick it up at runtime. The app is just an ordinary android app Ex: am, this is a galley app which can play videos..... But reinstalling the app is same as restarting the system... cached stuff is thrown out

Comment: Killing the app process is not enough? Your "driver" is simply a .so library that you load dynamically into the app process, right?

Comment: Ya ... that what I thought ... BTW by kill the app did u mean use kill command on the app ... My app plays a video for a few seconds and closes .... I did ps after the video ends and found that my app was not listed....

Comment: It is possible that Android (or zygote) is caching them at boot, at least [ro.zygote.disable_gl_preload](http://source.android.com/devices/tuning.html) indicates that it is capable of doing so. Also see ["speedup is achieved by NOT copying the shared libraries"](http://coltf.blogspot.de/p/android-os-processes-and-zygote.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `android apks` do cache the libraries. If you have installed `xyz.apk` on your board, then there will be folder created called `com.xyz`, this folder will contain a `cache` folder which will cache the libraries, so newly modified driver is not picked up by the `apk`.
To bypass this effect you can

1. Manually delete the `cache` folder from the above  mentioned location.
2. Uninstall the apk and re-install it agian
3. Reboot the board